# How can I send an email to all my customers in plesk 9.5.4?

Tags: email, plesk

we're about to migrate our server to a new one and there would be a little downtime. now, how can i inform all my customers in plesk?

they had to fill out a form with an email address at first login, but how can i get them all?

thanks for any advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to get all the email addresses of my clients.

In the mysql database, there is a database called `psa` and there is a table called `clients`. In this table are all clients and there is a column called email, so i exported the result of:

`SELECT email FROM clients WHERE email LIKE "%@%";`

To get all email addresses of all domains is a difficulter:

`SELECT CONCAT(a.mail_name, "@", b.name) AS email FROM mail AS a LEFT JOIN domains AS b ON a.dom_id = b.id;`

Hope this helps others with Plesk version < 10.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to send email to only active domains:

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.mail_name, "@", b.name) AS email FROM mail AS a LEFT JOIN domains AS b ON a.dom_id = b.id where domains.status=0;
```